# Button text not aligned center vertically in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, styles, text-alignment

I am facing one issue with aligning text vertically center for button but it remains slightly lower then exact center. 
I found `includeFontPadding` from documentation with suggesting some discrepancies with some third party font.

Font looks proper in iOS devices but it is not properly centered with Android.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text-style-props#includefontpadding

> Set to false to remove extra font padding intended to make space for certain ascenders / descenders. With some fonts, this padding can make text look slightly misaligned when centered vertically. For best results also set textAlignVertical to center. Default is true.

```
<Button
    style={[style.button]} block >
     <Text>Setup Now</Text>
  </Button>
```

Style for button:

```
export default {
  button: {
    elevation: null,
    shadowColor: null,
    shadowOffset: null,
    shadowOpacity: null,
    shadowRadius: null
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add also the used styles.

Comment: @Tim style added

Comment: Are you using the standard react-native Button?

Comment: @Tim: Yes I am using standard button

Comment: Sorry for asking again, could you please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? I think otherwise nobody can help you

Comment: I don't think you use react-native's Button component. If you are using react-native's Button component it will give you an error.

Comment: justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' may help

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 6):

Give this a try:

```
<Button style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
   <Text>Setup Now</Text>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using a Text component inside a Button Component.
Use the prop "title" as defined in the Button Documentation:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html

So your code will be

```
<Button
    style={[style.button]} title="Setup Now" block >
  </Button>
```

Comment: Can you please post screen with output ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using react native default button then react native default button does not support style properties and also Instead of using a Text component inside a Button Component. Use the properties "title" as defined in the official Documentation for that please refer the below link

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html

Also react native provide various options for button for your customisation button and as per your use for that please refer the below link

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches

Please try this below solution, may help for your issue.

```
<TouchableOpacity
      activeOpacity={.5}
      style={styles.buttonStyle}>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Setup Now</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>



buttonStyle: {
    padding: 14,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    borderRadius: 6,
  },

  textStyle: {
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can add style at your text for example `<Text style={styles.example}>TEST</Text>` and then add into your styles

`const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    example: {
        text-align:'center',
    } 
})`

maybe this can help for your reference

Answer (score 0):

You might try to add some styles to your text. It's actually mentioned directly in that snip you quoted from the docs:

> For best results also set textAlignVertical to center.

```
<Text style={[style.text]}>Setup now</Text>
```

With these styles:

```
export default {
  button: {
    ...
  },
  text: {
    flex: 1,   // fill the button
    textAlign: 'center',
    textAlignVertical: 'center',  // this style is Android only
  }
}
```